# How to make service run having all necessary code?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I inherited some code which included a service reference. I realized that the server the reference pointed was removed. I still have the code which included an .svc file. I guess that must be a WCF kind of a service, and I need to restore it on another server, but I have no idea how to do that.

As I said, the code includes an svc file, and also `Web.config`, `Web.Debug.config`, `Web.Release.config`, a project file, and some source files.

*Updated question with web.config*

```
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >

  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="ExcelConversionService.svc" 

         service="MyDomain.FileServices.ExcelConversionService"/>
  </serviceActivations>

</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host this service in IIS. please look at the following MSDN references

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734710.aspx

A more hands-on example is available at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/150066/Create-Host-Self-Hosting-IIS-hosting-and-Consume-W

Comment: Thank you Dhawalk... The article says e.g.: Just as with ASP.NET, you can deploy the implementation code for IIS-hosted WCF services in several ways at various locations, as follows:... As un-compiled code placed directly in the .svc file.   But it doesn't say how I should deploy it. Or I don't see it? Can I get some step-by-step instruction?

Comment: added a third link to the answer. please check this code project example. It talks about WCF development and various modes of deployment

Comment: Could you please tell me what path should I specify to add a service reference, if phisical path on server MyServer looks like this: C:\Services\FileConversionServices\ExcelConversionService.svc? Because in the example they deal with localhost... Thanks.

Comment: while adding service reference, you should always use a url. use the url that you have in your deployed web.config

Comment: I don't see any url there:    <?xml version="1.0"?><configuration><system.web><compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />  </system.web><system.serviceModel><behaviors><serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>

Comment: @DavidShochet I've copied this web.config and updated your question

Comment: @DavidShochet If you haven't specified an endpoint in your config, WCF uses the defaults.  Also it depends on your IIS configuration.  localhost will work if you are calling the service from the same box, otherwise you can use the ip address of the host machine

Comment: @EdmundYeung99  I have updated my question. Could you please tell how the http address should look now?